# Save report from Windows checking removable disk?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, screen-scraping

Is there any way to save a report of the errors that Windows found and fixed in a USB key? Windows presented me this dialog, btw that is not resizable:

[image: Checking Disk Removeable Disk (F:) - Some problems were found and fixed.]. 
<sub>Some problems were found and fixed.</sub>

When I open the details there is a long list of files with issues:

[image: Some problems were found and fixed (details)]
.

<sub>Some problems were found and fixed (details)</sub>

But there is no option to save a copy of the details to a text file. I could click Close and hope a report is saved somewhere but I'd like to be sure since there could be no going back.

I tried various text scraping tools such as [NirSoft's SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html) but it didn't recognize the details pane of the dialog so it couldn't extract what I need. Tried several others but no luck.

Any advice how to proceed?

CLARIFICATION: This scenario occurred automatically when I inserted one specific USB key into my computer, Windows prompted me that the key contains errors and would I like it to scan the key. I did not initiate this. I did not request a scan of the key using any tool like chkdsk or perf mon.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows Performance Monitor for this. (See image below).

[image]

For open the monitor, open the run box (press <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), type `perfmon` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For save reports, right click.

[image]

Comment: Please explain this answer in more detail as I don't see how it applies to my scenario. When I follow these steps I get a tiny text file that contains exactly this "Name Date\n".

Answer (score 0):

If you had started this from an admin "command prompt" you would have had a scroll bar.
chkdsk /x /r f:

Try this:
Left click next to just to the left of the "V" in volume.
then

open notepad

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that I did not start anything from the command prompt and did not run chkdsk.

Answer (score 0):

A report is saved somewhere, and the report is copy pastable too.

Go to the event viewer `%windir%\system32\eventvwr.msc /s`

[image: check1]

Select the application logs

[image: check2]

Bring up menu item Action, Find

[image: check3]

Type in chkdsk to find chkdsk entries

[image: check4]

When you find what your looking for double click on it, or Right click Properties
And as you can see , the event viewer allows text selection, and copy paste.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to check in event viewer. All I did was insert a USB key, so it is not "chkdsk" but something else that I need to search for. Any suggestion what event is triggered by inserting a USB key and that causes a disk check? I did try a search for "chkdsk" but it didn't return any recent results.

Comment: @JohnC There is one more thing at the link itself.

Comment: Two actually if you count "Event Viewer | Find 'wininit'" and PowerShell "get-winevent". Neither one turned up anything to correspond to the auto USB key scan from the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Run this powershell script to output all checkdsk entries from Eventlog into a text file:

```
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"}| ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | fl timecreated, message  > DRIVELETTER:\chkdsk.txt
```